# Determine most efficient order for a set of tasks with exclusive access to resources

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, task, computer-science

Given a set of resources and a set of tasks where each task needs exclusive access (write) to zero or more resources and shared access (read) to zero or more resources, how to I determine the most efficient order to execute them in (with parallel execution)?

Additionally, I'd like to know when I have to wait for the queued tasks to finish (if that's possible). I imagine the result to be like this, but I'm not sure about it:

Phase 1: Execute tasks A, E and Q

Phase 2: Execute tasks C, R and T

Phase 3: Execute tasks D, F and H
...

**EDIT:** Or maybe building up a dependency graph would be better because you do not have to wait for all the tasks?

Comment: Do you know the time taken to complete each task ? And I don't believe maximizing the gap between task is "efficient". If it was, the most efficient would be to never start the second task...

Comment: @fjardon No, not really. I will run these tasks very often (in that order), so I could measure it, but I don't think that it's worth it.

Comment: I think this is np-complete. You'd have to use heuristics to approximate a good-enough solution. There are a lot of similar problems, like finding a class schedule and assign teachers/rooms. Maybe knowing this can help you find ideas.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem class, but might be worth to have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Scheduling